# Running Matlab (.m) to Netbeans project without Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, netbeans

I have a netbeans (java) project and now I want to use my Matlab project (.m) to connect it with netbeans, so that I can run (.m) without Matlab.
I have Netbeans 8.0.2 and Matlab 7.0.
How can I fix this? Should I convert (.m) or what can I do? Thankyou.

Comment: You will need to convert your .m file to a .dll file and include that file in your project. Do you have the Matlab Compiler?

Comment: Am I have to download Matlab Compiler by myself or it has been included in Matlab?

Comment: You need the Matlab Compiler Toolkit (https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler.html). Information on how to use the compiler: http://de.mathworks.com/help/compiler/index.html